# Copy string to struct through pointer

Tags: c++, string, struct

The following code has some really weird behavior:

When chosen = 0, it returns -1073741819.

When chosen = 1, it runs but the output strings are messed up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* name[2] = {"WithoutSpaces","With spaces"};
struct entity{
    char* name;
};
struct entity *foo1, *foo2;

int main(void){
    foo1 = new entity;
    foo2 = new entity;
    int chosen = 1;

    foo1->name = new char[sizeof(name[chosen])+1];
    strcpy(foo1->name,name[chosen]);

    foo2->name = new char[sizeof(name[chosen])+1];
    strcpy(foo2->name,name[chosen]);

    cout << foo1->name <<endl;
    cout << foo2->name <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is happening?

Comment: `name[chosen]` is a pointer. `sizeof` a pointer is not what you need here. You need to find out the length of a string. But seriously, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Don't use char*  anc C-arrays in C++

Comment: You forgot to deallocate all the memory that you allocated dynamically.

Comment: What @juanchopanza said about `std::string` extends to smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. I see four `new`s without `delete`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
foo1->name = new char [strlen(name[chosen]) + 1];
strcpy(foo1->name, name[chosen]);
```

instead of

```
foo1->name = new char[sizeof(name[chosen])+1];
strcpy(foo1->name,name[chosen]);
```

Because sizeof(name[chosen]) returns you the size of the pointer "name[chosen]". And you need the length of the string, you can get that length with strlen function.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof will just return the size of the pointer

You could use `strlen`.
[strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `name[chosen]` is always `char *`, and `sizeof(char*)` is probably 4 or 8 (depending on platform). Because your allocation is too small, the strcpy() will overwrite unallocated memory, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean sizeof(char*) ?

Comment: @H.Guijt: It does now (now that Mat has fixed the markup), but before, your `*` characters were being treated as "make italic" markup.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that. I haven't really gotten the hang of markup yet. Is there a description of available markup codes somewhere?